# Inheritance and Constructors in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

am doing an application to keep track of employees in a firm. There are different classes of employees, which all inherit from the abstract class Employee. What I want is to define an static variable in the class Employee that will represent the id which will be given to each employee once it is initialized, then incremented.So my question is, how do I implement a constructor for for example the class Manager which inherits from Employee, without passing an ID as a parameter, but is going to be determined once it reaches the constructor of the class Employee?

Comment: You can't have a static variable that is unique per instance of a class.

Comment: I know, but i want to pass the value from the static variable to a new non-static variable in the class that inherits from Employee

Comment: This is homework, shows a poor understanding of the subject and no example code, isn't clearly versed.

Comment: Also, assigning Ids in that fashion is a disaster waiting to happen.
There is no way you can guarantee that the employees will always be retreived in the same order. Chances are they will have a different ID every single time

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee
{
    static int _empCount = 0;
    static int GetNextEmployeeId()
    {
        _empCount++;
        return _empCount;
    }

    public int EmployeeId { get; private set; }

    public Employee()
    {
        EmployeeId = GetNextEmployeeId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is simpler than I imagined doing it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

namespace Project1
{

```
class Employee
{

    static int lastId;

    protected int id;

    public Employee()
    {
        this.id = lastId + 1;
        lastId = this.id;
    }


}

class Manager : Employee
{
    public Manager() : base() { }
}

class Accountant : Employee
{
    public Accountant() : base() { }
}
```

}

Comment: You should correct formatting of your code. Add 4 spaces before each line. Remove empty lines